# Bash on iOS issue

Tags: ios, bash, jailbreak

When any application that uses bash to launch their executables as root, iOS registers the bash script as the main executable instead of the intended executable.

The problem is that I cannot turn off cellular access to these applications because iOS calls the script rather than the applications executable and nothing happens.

I found a partial method that works, but it's not practical because the application looses root capabilities, but it will allow the setting's app to disable cellular data for the application;

1. `Remove the bash script,`
2. `Rename the apps main executable to the bash scrips name,`
3. `Reboot.`

Can I do anything to solve this?

Thanks, Jason.

Comment: Can you access the `su` command?

Comment: Yes, I have access to a full fledged terminal :)